# without using nested loop how to merge two list of dictionaries by same key in python

Tags: python

I have two list of dicts:

```
first_list = [{
                "symbol": "BTC",
                "price": 22809
               },
              {
                "symbol": "ETH",
                "price": 1626
              }
             ]

second_list = [{
                "symbol": "BTC",
                "volume": 22809333
               },
              {
                "symbol": "ETH",
                "volume": 19809333
              }
             ]
```

What is the best solution (without for or another bad time complexibility solutions) to merge two lists like:

```
final_list = [{
                "symbol": "BTC",
                "price": 22809,
                "volume": 22809333
               },
              {
                "symbol": "ETH",
                "price": 1626,
                "volume": 19809333
              }
             ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

out = [{**u, **v} for u, v in zip_longest(first_list, second_list, fillvalue={})]

#print(out)
[{'symbol': 'BTC', 'price': 22809, 'volume': 22809333},
 {'symbol': 'ETH', 'price': 1626, 'volume': 19809333}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The community would appreciate if in addition to code you can provide a description / extensive comments to improve it. For example, I think it is a great opportunity to explain (or point to relevant documentation) how `zip_longest` works or what `{**u, **v}` does.

Comment: The important thing about using the zip_longest method is that the items in the lists must be sorted and similar items must be compressed together.
Unless your data is wrong and you are not aware of it.

Comment: The best thing to do is to sort both lists based on a specific element and check when combining

Comment: first_list = sorted(first_list, key=lambda x: x.get('symbol'))
second_list = sorted(second_list, key=lambda x: x.get('symbol'))

final_list = [u | v for u, v in zip_longest(first_list, second_list, fillvalue={})
                    if u.get('symbol') == v.get('symbol')]